# Keeping dynamic out of SQL while using specifications with stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

A specification essentially is a text string representing a "where" clause created by an end user.

I have stored procedures that copy a set of related tables and records to other places.  The operation is always the same, but dependent on some crazy user requirements like "products that are frozen and blue and on sale on Tuesday".

What if we fed the user specification (or string parameter) to a scalar function that returned true/false which executed the specification as dynamic SQL or just exec (@variable).
It could tell us whether those records exist.  We could add the result of the function to our copy products where clause.

It would keep us from recompiling the copy script each time our where clauses changed.  Plus it would isolate the product selection in to a single function.

Anyone ever do anything like this or have examples?  What bad things could come of it?

EDIT:

This is the specification I simply added to the end of each insert/select statement:

```
and exists (
    select null as nothing
    from SameTableAsOutsideTable inside
    where inside.ID = outside.id and      -- Join operations to outside table

          inside.page in (6, 7) and       -- Criteria 1
          inside.dept in (7, 6, 2, 4)     -- Criteria 2
)
```

It would be great to feed a parameter into a function that produces records based on the user criteria, so all that above could be something like:

```
and dbo.UserCriteria( @page="6,7", @dept="7,6,2,4")
```

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to build a query builder to determine if data exists prior to doing the actual copy operation?

Comment: To use Exists() to identify what records to copy based on user criteria.

Comment: The worst thing about the proposed function is probably the performance - your function will get called once for every record; if performance is irrelevant (eg a rare process on a table with little data), then this approach may indeed be cleaner.

Comment: +1 for Tao.  I was wondering why it was so slow.  I changed the UDFs to temp tables and it increased performance by about five seconds.  Amazing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html)

When optimizing SQL the important thing is optimizing the access path to data (ie. index usage). This trumps code reuse, maintainability,  nice formatting and just about every other development perk you can think of. This is because a bad access path will cause the query to perform hundreds of times slower than it should. The article linked sums up very well all the options you have, and your envisioned function is nowhere on the radar. Your options will gravitate around dynamic SQL or very complicated static queries. I'm afraid there is no free lunch on this topic.

Comment: You can pretty much never go wrong with following Erland's advice on anything SQL

Comment: Good read.  I tried sending List<string> to SQL 2005 table valued parameters, but it doesn't support them.  That would be ideal in this situation.

Comment: I think it supports List<DBDataRecord>

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't sound like a very good idea to me. Even supposing that you had proper defensive coding to avoid SQL injection attacks it's not going to really buy you anything. The code still needs to be "compiled" each time.

Also, it's pretty much always a bad idea to let users create free-form WHERE clauses. Users are pretty good at finding new and innovative ways to bring a server to a grinding halt.

If you or your users or someone else in the business can't come up with some concrete search requirements then it's likely that someone isn't thinking about it hard enough and doesn't really know what they want. You can have pretty versatile search capabilities without letting the users completely loose on the system. Alternatively, look at some of the BI tools out there and consider creating a data mart where they can do these kinds of ad hoc searches.

Comment: It's advertising. They reuse content from previous weeks to slightly modify for this week, copying content based on ever changing criteria. There are thousands of similar records across six to twelve tables. The copy is simple enough.  If this were C# and Linq, I would simply create a delegate function and send it to the data service.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:
You create another store procedure (instead of function) and pass the right condition to it.
Based on that condition it dumps the record ids to a temp table.

Next you move procedure will read ids from that table and do the needful things?

Or you could create a user function that returns a table which is nothing but the ids of the records that matches your criteria (dynamic)

If I am totally off, then please clarify me.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's what I was thinking.  Now the question is how to code it using TSQL?  If we had a table valued function that took criteria and produced empty records like the example, it would certainly select the right records.

Comment: Pass your criteria to the second stored proc OR user defined function. Next you build a dynamic query based on the parameter. Do a print on the dynamic sql. Then try to execute that dynamic sql to see it returns the right set of ids. You just need the matching ids dumped by the store proc or func to some temporary table. Once you have the data dumped to a temp table, all you need is to join with the main table to do what you need. Hope this helps.

Comment: Tried a UDF which executed for each joined record (ouch.)  Next tried a temp table without index (no recompile) and it was lightning fast. (where page in (select value from #somelist )).  The key would be to not recompile the SP each time.  It's 2005 so no table parameters, which would be ideal.  However, it probably optimizes the SP based on parameter values.  Maybe I should make a SP for each parameter variation (which would be fast but not practical.)  Maybe recompiling the SP each execution is not a bad thing, which would push me back to Dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1):

If you are forced to use dynamic queries and you don't have any solid and predefined search requirements, it is strongly recommended to use `sp_executesql` instead of `EXEC` . It provides parametrized queries to prevent SQL Injection attacks (to some extent) and It makes use of execution plans to speed up performance. ([More info](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCAQFjAB&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx&ei=er7WTfmvK4zNsgaQgeG1Bw&usg=AFQjCNGjQSFvBRhz0y_FraF8zYR3pvVbjQ))